# Partition of tablespace

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces

My postgres server is running in a windows server and three tablespace are created. Postgresql server is installed in C: drive and the tablespaces are in D: and E: drive. So how to take a backup and restore. Is it similar to normal backup and while restore, in another machine, do i need to have the same setup or i can restore it in a single drive? From the tablespace folder, is it possible to retreive information for only one table which is huge?

Comment: How do you (intend to) backup - [FS-level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-file.html), [SQL dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html), any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few backup options for you.

A standard dump (pg_dump) will be restorable on another machine but you may want to create the tablespaces first before restoring.  Where the tablespaces are is not really a concern for the recovery.  Note you can also do pg_dump -Fc and this will allow you to select tables to restore at restore time.

Another option is to use pg_basebackup if you are on 9.1 or higher and this will rebuild your data directories over replication.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgbasebackup.html for more on this option.